# What are the fundamental classes documentations in the Apple Dev Center to read for newbies?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Sorry if this is an annoying question, but I'm new to iOS development and since allot of people always tells me it's important to read Apple documentations, and there are alooot of them, so I though you can maybe list some of the Fundamental ones for newbies to begin with.

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I read, in this order:

- Object Oriented Programming with Objective-C
- Your first iOS app
- The Objective-C programming language
- Cocoa fundamentals guide
- Objective-C runtime programming guide (skimmed)
- View controller programming guide for iOS
- Text,web and editing programming guide for iOS.
- Core Data tutorial for iOS

There is some repetition/overlapping between these guides so after the first three or so it will be a fast read.

Don't bother buying guides and cookbooks: they just regurgitate what's in the official documentation. Once you are finished reading the basic documentation watch some videos of Apple's WWDC (for free on iTunes) of topics of your interest, ad especially the talk about ARC (about memory management).

**UPDATE:**
Concerning classes you'll just check them as you need to use them. Probably the most used are the controllers (UINavigationController, UIViewController..), NSString, UIButton, UITextView, UILabel and all the containers (NSArray, NSMutableArray, NSSet, NSDictionary..). However I would not try to study them before you need them in your code. It's just the more you use them the easier it will be to do so.

Comment: +1 Note all the references to "...Programming Guide." Apple PGs are where you want to start, not specific class references.

Comment: Don't forget about memory management...

Comment: @lnafziger thank you. I have read already an Objective C book "Programming in Objective C" and there was a chapter on memory management, but isn't since we wre using ARC now so it mostly about understanding `strong , weak , copy , retain` ?

Comment: @JohnBigs yeah now almost everything works with ARC, except sometimes for CoreFoundation stuff. There is a great WWDC video (2010 or 2011) about ARC that explains everything.

Comment: Well, keep in mind that not all code is using ARC, particularly code that has been around since before ARC was introduced and Core Foundation code.  Also, ARC is just automating the memory management and it is still going on behind the scenes so it is good to know.  The Memory Management Guide should still be part of the required reading list for anyone wanting to program for Apple products.

Comment: @Inafziger I would not consider Memory Management Guide for beginners given that in most cases you won't need that level of detail using ARC, or also using CoreFoundation, which in itself is not very beginner. I believe the basic concepts of retain, release are touched in many of the above documents as well as the ARC talk.

Comment: Hermione: I disagree. I think that too many people view this as an advanced subject when it is actually a fundamental basis of programming.  This gets them into trouble later as they progress in their learning!  While you can "cheat" and get away without it for awhile (IF you are using ARC) dropping down to CF is often needed, even if for short snippets, and understanding memory management is critical.

Comment: @lnafziger I agree with you. I'm learning it too, and I would say to anyone that will ask me, that he should take the time to at list understand what's going on behind the scens. Of course he should use ARC, but understanding Manual memory management is actually make the future learning easier.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some links for iOS technology:

- [iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072): Explains from basic to high level concepts of iOS programming
- [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210): Regarding How to do programming in Objective-C
- [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000146i): A developer should follow language/platform specific coding rules/guidelines. Here is the Cocoa guidelines, so while writing your code please ensure that all this rules are getting satisfied.

While learning/searching, please refer [Apple iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/) at first priority, otherwise search engines are there to help you out.

Hope this information will help you to start up in iOS application development.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to read and with out knowing what you are looking for this is close to impossible. I'd suggest starting with CS 193P iPhone Application Development by the Stanford University online course (which you can find on iTunesU) that summarize everything in a more efficient way than just reading the documentation but if you insist the NSString class is a good way to start.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html